# Table styling with LESS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, less

This question is about styling a table which is created inside an AngularJS directive. I have an array of objects passed to the directive from HTML file. The directive creates a table and shows each object of the array in a row.

**Now my question:** There is a self-defined JSON field in each object called **name**. Styling is done by LESS technology and I want to have a thick separating line behind each row when **'name == david'**. Please consider this condition can be different for example when 'rowID%3 ==0' and etc. My general question is how can I access this objects in LESS file and how can I make conditional styling inside LESS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a lot of assumptions since you didn't include any code or markup, but in Angular this is a very basic, simple problem, and is independent of whether you are using LESS, Sass, or just plain CSS:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index" ng-class="{'thick-separator': isNameDavid(item) || $index%3 == 0}">
      <td>{{item.propOne}}</td>
      <td>{{item.propTwo}}</td>
      <td>{{item.propThree}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.isNameDavid = function(item) {
  return item.name == 'david';
};
```

Using the `ngClass` directive and the `$index` scope variable that is introduced by the `ngRepeat` directive, you can easily assign a `thick-separator` class to table rows, conditionally.

Now, it makes no difference if you are using LESS, Sass, or plain CSS:

```
.thick-seperator {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

If, however, you are trying to say that you can't change the Angular code and you need to be able to style purely with LESS, then you can style using attribute and `nth-child` selectors. Note that these are available in plain CSS and LESS is not needed:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(3n+3), table tbody tr[data-name="david"] {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Dear Joel, the first approach, with conditional ng-class is what I am exactly looking for. However, it does not work because the evaluation of item.name == 'david' is not executed. I tried following, and it works: ng-class="{'thick-separator': true } and it adds the LESS class to all rows. But when I add condition instead of true, it is not evaluated at all. Do you think syntax is a problem somewhere ?

Comment: Yes. There is a syntax issue there with quotes. It's better, actually, to use a controller method. So instead of `item.name == 'david'` you would write `isNameDavid(item)` and in your controller you could define the `$scope.isNameDavid = function(item){ return item.name == 'david'; }`

Comment: Perfect. This idea worked very well and better. I could send the item as the parameter into scope function and make a decision there. Thanks a million Joel.